# Why doesn't StringLength work with ASP.NET MVC unobtrusive validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, selectlist

Why does [StringLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx) cause spurious errors on a select list:

```
[StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2)]
```

should require that the values be strings of length 2.  However, it causes client-side errors even when all the values meet that constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Unobtrusive translates it to [`rangelength`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/rangelength), which for select boxes checks the number of selected items, not the lengths of the selected value(s).